# TSC 5.3.3. throwing errors building massivedecks 2

Tags: typescript

I am trying to stand up an instance of massivedecks 2.  When compiling the server (or at least I am inferring I am compiling the server -- everything is hidden behind assorted scripts), I am getting a series of errors:

```
*> npx tsc*

src/ts/action/validation.validator.ts:21:1 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'typeof import("/md/server/node_modules/ajv-formats/dist/index")' has no call signatures.

21 addFormats(ajv, { mode: "full" });
   ~~~~~~~~~~

src/ts/caches/postgres.ts:209:11 - error TS18047: 'result.rowCount' is possibly 'null'.

209       if (result.rowCount > 0) {
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/ts/caches/postgres.ts:241:11 - error TS18047: 'about.rowCount' is possibly 'null'.

241       if (about.rowCount > 0 && about.rows[0]["cards_updated"] !== undefined) {
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/ts/store/postgres.ts:138:5 - error TS2322: Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'.

138     return await this.pg.withClient(async (client) => {
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
139       const result = await client.query(
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
... 
147       return result.rowCount;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
148     });
    ~~~~~~~

src/ts/store/postgres.ts:243:11 - error TS18047: 'get.rowCount' is possibly 'null'.

243       if (get.rowCount < 1) {
```

Not being well versed in TypeScript, I do not have a good idea of why these errors are getting thrown or how to pull back on the error to ascertain the root cause.  Any help would be appreciated.

I am trying to ascertain the root cause, but my unfamiliarity with TypeScript is a barrier here.